# How to use powershell to set directory details

Tags: windows, powershell, filesystems

Being able to set directory view requirements is useful for any Windows user. I have a lot of music files in various directories. So manually setting a music specific view is a pain. What I would like is to write a Powershell script that set a particular display for a given list of directories.

[image: directory view requirements]

Using `PS C:\apsTest> Get-ChildItem | Get-Member` in Powershell gives me a lot of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` properties/methods for my directory. But none of these includes a description like View, Details

Directory methods like `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` and properties like `Attributes` don't seem to deal with this. For example this tutorial [Use a PowerShell Cmdlet to Work with File Attributes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-a-powershell-cmdlet-to-work-with-file-attributes/) goes into quite some detail but not in my area of interest.

Comment: There's no solution at the level of the _file-system_ (such as via attributes), because what you're looking for relates to the view configuration of the [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all, are you making use of the various *FolderTypes*
   available via the `Customize` tab in a folder's `Properties` dialog?
   Or are you wanating more than one view layout available to `Music`
   folders?
2. Are you aware you can use `Apply to Folders` to save a *customized* verison of any *Folderype*?
3. Have you exploreed the various views of files offered by *Libraries* in **Explorer**? The real beauty of *Libraries* is hidden away in the background context menu -- `Arrange by`. For a `Music Library` you have:

   - The default, `Folder`, the least interesting:

     [image]
   - `Album` -- Song titles *stacked* by album. a much better presentation of Album Art than a regular folder thumbnail. And when you navigate into an album, you see only the songs -- a nice, clean look:

     [image]

     [image]
   - `Artist` -- Albums *stacked* by artist.

     [image]
   - `Song` -- a flat list of all song titles:

     [image]
   - `Genre` -- Albums *stacked* by genre:

     [image]
   - `Rating` -- Song titles grouped by rating.

     [image]

And you can define as many custom libraries including as many or as few folders as you want. Each library would save unique view settings.

---

---

As far as scripting goes, manipulating the templates and saved views stored in the registry is a somewhat advanced, detailed task. But I could go into it if you desire.

There is a limited set of view properties that are easily manipulated for an *active* **Explorer** window via the `shell.applicaton` COM object.

For simplicity of demonstration, open a single **Explorer** window. Then in **PowerShell**, copy the following code:

```
$shell = New-Object -com shell.application
$window = @($shell.Windows())[0]
$window | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
$window.Document | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
$window.Document
```

You'll see output similar to the following:

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{d30c1661-cdaf-11d0-8a3e-00c04fc9e26e}

Name                 MemberType Definition
----                 ---------- ----------
AddressBar           Property   bool AddressBar () {get} {set}
Application          Property   IDispatch Application () {get}
Busy                 Property   bool Busy () {get}
Container            Property   IDispatch Container () {get}
Document             Property   IDispatch Document () {get}
FullName             Property   string FullName () {get}
FullScreen           Property   bool FullScreen () {get} {set}
Height               Property   int Height () {get} {set}
HWND                 Property   int64 HWND () {get}
Left                 Property   int Left () {get} {set}
LocationName         Property   string LocationName () {get}
LocationURL          Property   string LocationURL () {get}
MenuBar              Property   bool MenuBar () {get} {set}
Name                 Property   string Name () {get}
Offline              Property   bool Offline () {get} {set}
Parent               Property   IDispatch Parent () {get}
Path                 Property   string Path () {get}
ReadyState           Property   tagREADYSTATE ReadyState () {get}
RegisterAsBrowser    Property   bool RegisterAsBrowser () {get} {set}
RegisterAsDropTarget Property   bool RegisterAsDropTarget () {get} {set}
Resizable            Property   bool Resizable () {get} {set}
Silent               Property   bool Silent () {get} {set}
StatusBar            Property   bool StatusBar () {get} {set}
StatusText           Property   string StatusText () {get} {set}
TheaterMode          Property   bool TheaterMode () {get} {set}
ToolBar              Property   int ToolBar () {get} {set}
Top                  Property   int Top () {get} {set}
TopLevelContainer    Property   bool TopLevelContainer () {get}
Type                 Property   string Type () {get}
Visible              Property   bool Visible () {get} {set}
Width                Property   int Width () {get} {set}


   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{29ec8e6c-46d3-411f-baaa-611a6c9cac66}

Name            MemberType Definition
----            ---------- ----------
Application     Property   IDispatch Application () {get}
CurrentViewMode Property   uint CurrentViewMode () {get} {set}
FocusedItem     Property   FolderItem FocusedItem () {get}
Folder          Property   Folder Folder () {get}
FolderFlags     Property   uint FolderFlags () {get} {set}
GroupBy         Property   string GroupBy () {get} {set}
IconSize        Property   int IconSize () {get} {set}
Parent          Property   IDispatch Parent () {get}
Script          Property   IDispatch Script () {get}
SortColumns     Property   string SortColumns () {get} {set}
ViewOptions     Property   int ViewOptions () {get}

Application     : System.__ComObject
Parent          :
Folder          : System.__ComObject
FocusedItem     : System.__ComObject
Script          :
ViewOptions     : 139
CurrentViewMode : 4
GroupBy         : System.Null
FolderFlags     : 1090519041
SortColumns     : prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;
IconSize        : 16
```

- `CurrentViewMode` specifies the icon mode using the following enumeration:

  - `1` -- Icon mode  (affected by IconSoze)
  - `3` -- List
  - `4` -- Details
  - `6` -- Tiles
  - `8` -- Content
- `GroupBy` -- specifies the property to group on/
- `SortColumns` -- Properties to sort on.
- `IconSize` -- self-explanatory

So, if you wanted to switch a window from its current icon mode to `Tiles`, you would execute:

```
$shell.Document.CurrentViewMode = 6
```

In additon, the Docuement object has the `FilterView()` method. This allows you to execute a search of the folder using a string identical to what you would type in the Search bar in **Explorer**:

```
$shell.Document.FilterView("name:A*.mp3")
```

to search for all .mp3 files whose name begins with 'A'.

So there are a lot of options. Use the comments for brief queston/ansers, but edit you question to better describe what you want, and I'll edit this answer accordingly.

---

### Edit #1 -- Overriding view mode for a newly-creaeted folder

---

```
$pPath     = 'C:\Path\to\folder'   # the soon-to-be parent of new folders
$shell     = New-Object -com shell.application

$VerbosePreference = Continue

$currWin   = @($shell.Windows())
If ($pPath -in $currWin.Document.Folder.Self.Path)
{           # target folder already open, use existing window
    $win   = $currWin.Where{$_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -eq $pPath}
            Write-Verbose ('Using current window: {0}' -f $win.LocationName)
}
Else
{               # open new window to target folder
    $shell.ShellExecute($pPath,"","","",1)
    While ($shell.Windows().Count -eq $CurrWin.Count)
    {
        Write-Verbose 'Waiting for new window...';sleep -m 50
    }
    $win   = @($shell.Windows() | where {$_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -eq $pPath})
            Write-Verbose ('Using new window: {0}' -f $win.LocationName)
}

### If you're looping to create multiple folders, start loop here

$newFolder = 'MyNewFolder'
$win.Document.Folder.NewFolder($newFolder)

While ($newFolder -notIn (gci $pPath -ad -Name))
{
    Write-Verbose 'Waiting for new folder...';sleep -m 10
}

# Navigate to the new folder by "double-clicking"
$win.Document.Folder.ParseName($newFolder).InvokeVerb()

While ($win.ReadyState -ne 4)
{
    Write-Verbose 'Navigating to new folder...';sleep -m 10
}

# Set the view mode
$win.Document.CurrentViewMode = 6   # 6 = Tiles

# Navigating away from the folder saves the view
$win.GoBack()

### If looping, loop here
```

Comment: Thank you. The shell.applicaton COM object looks like the approach for me. Just a note regarding music storage/display. I am sorry. Perhaps I should have said. But I was looking more to manage my own music. I record using Reaper https://www.reaper.fm/ I produce a lot of files that need managing. Several different extensions. I was looking to set up a file structure template that would accommodate a typical recording project. So I appreciate the effort you have gone to. You've been a great help.

Comment: You're welcome. I just want to make sure you don't do more work than you have to. *Any* view template (default or customzied) found under the `Customize` tab can apply to *any* folder (and optionally, its subfolders). There are also several "specialty" templates you could "hijack" for your own purposes. I could be much more specific if you provided concrete examples and/or screenshots...

Comment: I have your example working (eg changing `CurrentViewMode` for object properties output to screen & seeing change in example File Explorer window) But I can't see how to associate this functionality with a specific directory. For example: after calling `New-Item` to create a directory. How do I apply the `CurrentViewMode` shell property specifically to this directory in order for it to have the `CurrentViewMode` set by default?

Comment: A newly-created folder has no view saved under `HKCU\...\Bags`, so the first time it is opened in **Explorer**, the `CurrentViewMode` *and all other aspects of that view*, will be determined by the `FolderType` assigned to that folder by **Explorer**. **Explorer** assigns the `FolderType` byfist checking for inheritance specified by any of its ancestors in the namespace path. then checking for desktop.ini settings. If neither exists, it defaults based on locaton and/or content-sniffing. But, if the parent has been included in a Library, viewing via the Library will impose those views.

Comment: Answer edited -- demo code for new folder creation/icon mode override.

Comment: For code down to `# If other windows are open, we need to know their handles
$currHWND = @(@($shell.Windows()).HWND)` If I do `$currHWND | Get-Member` I get an object with a collection of methods. So I don't understand how the following line `$newWin = @($shell.Windows() | Where-Object HWND -notIn $currHWND)[0]` is going to work?

Comment: `$currHWND ` is simply an array of integer values that are guaranteed to be unique because they are window handles. PIping to `gm` is simply showing you all the methods available to integers. So `$newWin = @($shell.Windows() | Where-Object HWND -notIn $currHWND)[0]` is filtering open windows *by Handle* and returning only the window that was  opened by `$shell.ShellExecute()` .

Comment: I am getting a null-valued expression for `$newWin = @($shell.Windows() | Where-Object HWND -notIn $currHWND)[0]`

Comment: That could happen if you already have a window open to the same folder specified by $pPath. Also, now it may be open but hidden. Execute `@($shell.Windows()).Quit()` to close all Explorer windows, including hidden, before trying again.

Comment: I edited t;he edit to provide a more robust version of the code. Take note of hte timing loops --- they prevent the script from getting ahead of the window. Combined with the `Write-Verbose` info, they make you quickly aware if stuck in a lopp, as well as helping fine-tune the sleep vales.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. When I ran script, with no File Explorer windows open, a new folder `myNewFolder` was created, in the target folder. And `myNewFolder` had a Tiles View. However I noticed in the debug output that the code run entered the `if` and not the `else` branch. Given that I had no open folders in File Explorer your comment `# target folder already open, use existing window` confused me. With this in mind it may be useful to clarify the difference in terms between the words `folder` and `window`. Just a thought :)

Comment: What did the `Write-Verbose` output indicate?

Comment: I was confused. The if else branching works as intended.

Comment: I think I understand `While ($win.ReadyState -ne 4)` as a call, to wait for, the object to receive all its data. What I don't get is the repeat lines in the corresponding verbose output `VERBOSE: Target folder already open
VERBOSE: Using current window: musicTest
VERBOSE: Navigating to new folder...
VERBOSE: Navigating to new folder...` Why the two lines `Navigating to new folder`?

Comment: Because the message prints once for every loop of the `While` statement. So it took sometime between 20ms and 30ms for the window to navigate to your new folder, display it, and be "ready" for whatever comes at it next.  Perhaps "Waiting for navigation to complete..." would be better verbiage --- change it to whatever makes sense to YOU! If you saw 10 - 15 messages consistently, then it would make sense to up the value of the `sleep` command. If any loop message starts scrolling off the screen rapildly, your code is stuck in a loop --- you need to halt execution and trouble-shoot.