# Turn on/off specific columns in file explorer details view

Tags: powershell, file, explorer

Similar to that topic:
[How to use powershell to set directory details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999619/how-to-use-powershell-to-set-directory-details)

I am wondering if it is possible to switch on or off specific columns in details view of explorer using powershell. @Keith Miller?

With the topic mentioned above, I am able to switch view setting, change sorting column. But I didn't found how to turn on specific columns in file explorer details view.